Python automation - Connection establishment with selenium server is failing
I have created a docker compose file to create the containers for Selenium, chromedriver and python behave(framework),

version: '3'

services:
  selenium:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"

  chromedriver:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:latest
    links:
      - selenium:hub

  behave-tests:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/behave-tests
    depends_on:
      - selenium
      - chromedriver
    environment:
      - SELENIUM_HOST=selenium
      - SELENIUM_PORT=4444


FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /behave-tests

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["behave"]

Tried to test few testcase with python where I am trying to establish conection with selenium server by customizing the chrome driver options. This is throwing the error
"raise NewConnectionError(
behave-tests-1  |       urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7efdf3e505e0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused
"
from behave import *
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

@step('Chrome browser launch')
def step_impl(context):
    selenium_host = os.getenv('SELENIUM_HOST', 'localhost')
    selenium_port = os.getenv('SELENIUM_PORT', '4444')
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')  # Example option: run in headless mode
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')  # Example option
    CHROME_DRIVER_PATH = f"http://{selenium_host}:{selenium_port}/wd/hub"
    context.driver = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor=CHROME_DRIVER_PATH,
        options=chrome_options
    )


